# Create normal zip file programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, compression, zip

I have seen many tutorials on how to compress a single file in c#. But I need to be able to create a normal *.zip file out of more than just one file. Is there anything in .NET that can do this? What would you suggest (baring in mind I'm under strict rules and cannot use other libraries)

Thank you

Comment: When using .NET's `ZipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile`, be careful with your parameters and make sure you're not using the absolute path for the `entryName` parameter. You'll get no warning, the zip file will be made, and it will be empty. You can use `Path.GetFileName(filePath)` if you're dealing with strings instead of .NET's filesytem objects, which would allow use of `obj.Name`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Edit: if you're using .Net 4.5 or later this is [built-in to the framework](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19613011/444991)

For earlier versions or for more control you can use Windows' shell functions as outlined [here on CodeProject by Gerald Gibson Jr](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/compresswithwinshellapics.aspx).

I have copied the article text below as written (original license: [public domain](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/publicdomain/))

> ### Compress Zip files with Windows Shell API and C
>
> [image]
>
> #### Introduction
>
> This is a follow up article to the one that I wrote about decompressing Zip files. With this code you can use the Windows Shell API in C# to compress Zip files and do so without having to show the Copy Progress window shown above. Normally when you use the Shell API to compress a Zip file, it will show a Copy Progress window even when you set the options to tell Windows not to show it. To get around this, you move the Shell API code to a separate executable and then launch that executable using the .NET Process class being sure to set the process window style to 'Hidden'.
>
> #### Background
>
> Ever needed to compress Zip files and needed a better Zip than what comes with many of the free compression libraries out there? I.e. you needed to compress folders and subfolders as well as files. Windows Zipping can compress more than just individual files. All you need is a way to programmatically get Windows to silently compress these Zip files. Of course you could spend $300 on one of the commercial Zip components, but it's hard to beat free if all you need is to compress folder hierarchies.
>
> #### Using the code
>
> The following code shows how to use the Windows Shell API to compress a Zip file. First you create an empty Zip file. To do this create a properly constructed byte array and then save that array as a file with a '.zip' extension. How did I know what bytes to put into the array? Well I just used Windows to create a Zip file with a single file compressed inside. Then I opened the Zip with Windows and deleted the compressed file. That left me with an empty Zip. Next I opened the empty Zip file in a hex editor (Visual Studio) and looked at the hex byte values and converted them to decimal with Windows Calc and copied those decimal values into my byte array code. The source folder points to a folder you want to compress. The destination folder points to the empty Zip file you just created. This code as is will compress the Zip file, however it will also show the Copy Progress window. To make this code work, you will also need to set a reference to a COM library. In the References window, go to the COM tab and select the library labeled 'Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation'.

```
//Create an empty zip file
byte[] emptyzip = new byte[]{80,75,5,6,0,0,0,0,0, 
                  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

FileStream fs = File.Create(args[1]);
fs.Write(emptyzip, 0, emptyzip.Length);
fs.Flush();
fs.Close();
fs = null;

//Copy a folder and its contents into the newly created zip file
Shell32.ShellClass sc = new Shell32.ShellClass();
Shell32.Folder SrcFlder = sc.NameSpace(args[0]);
Shell32.Folder DestFlder = sc.NameSpace(args[1]); 
Shell32.FolderItems items = SrcFlder.Items();
DestFlder.CopyHere(items, 20);

//Ziping a file using the Windows Shell API 
//creates another thread where the zipping is executed.
//This means that it is possible that this console app 
//would end before the zipping thread 
//starts to execute which would cause the zip to never 
//occur and you will end up with just
//an empty zip file. So wait a second and give 
//the zipping thread time to get started
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

> The sample solution included with this article shows how to put this code into a console application and then launch this console app to compress the Zip without showing the Copy Progress window.
>
> The code below shows a button click event handler that contains the code used to launch the console application so that there is no UI during the compress:

```
private void btnUnzip_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //Test to see if the user entered a zip file name
    if(txtZipFileName.Text.Trim() == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must enter what" + 
               " you want the name of the zip file to be");
        //Change the background color to cue the user to what needs fixed
        txtZipFileName.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        //Reset the background color
        txtZipFileName.BackColor = Color.White;
    }

    //Launch the zip.exe console app to do the actual zipping
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo i =
        new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "zip.exe");
    i.CreateNoWindow = true;
    string args = "";

    
    if(txtSource.Text.IndexOf(" ") != -1)
    {
        //we got a space in the path so wrap it in double qoutes
        args += "\"" + txtSource.Text + "\"";
    }
    else
    {
        args += txtSource.Text;
    }

    string dest = txtDestination.Text;

    if(dest.EndsWith(@"\") == false)
    {
        dest += @"\";
    }

    //Make sure the zip file name ends with a zip extension
    if(txtZipFileName.Text.ToUpper().EndsWith(".ZIP") == false)
    {
        txtZipFileName.Text += ".zip";
    }

    dest += txtZipFileName.Text;

    if(dest.IndexOf(" ") != -1)
    {
        //we got a space in the path so wrap it in double qoutes
        args += " " + "\"" + dest + "\"";
    }
    else
    {
        args += " " + dest;
    }

    i.Arguments = args;
    

    //Mark the process window as hidden so 
    //that the progress copy window doesn't show
    i.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;    
    System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(i);
    p.WaitForExit();
    MessageBox.Show("Complete");
}
```

Comment: Since .NET 4.5, you can accomplish this using  `System.IO.Compression.ZipFile`; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19613011/444991) for more details

Answer (score 74):

Just an update on this for anyone else who stumbles across this question.

Starting in .NET 4.5 you are able to compress a directory using `System.IO.Compression` into a zip file. You have to add `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem` as a reference as it is not referenced by default. Then you can write:

```
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(dirPath, zipFile);
```

The only potential problem is that this assembly is not available for Windows Store Apps.

Comment: There is no support for password protection either.

Answer (score 56):

You can now use the [**ZipArchive**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) class (System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive), available from .NET 4.5

You have to add `System.IO.Compression` as a reference.

Example: Generating a zip of PDF files

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\temp.zip", FileMode.CreateNew))
{
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
        foreach (var creditNumber in creditNumbers)
        {
            var pdfBytes = GeneratePdf(creditNumber);
            var fileName = "credit_" + creditNumber + ".pdf";
            var zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(fileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
            using (var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open())
            {
                zipStream.Write(pdfBytes, 0, pdfBytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using VB.NET, fastest way to get file bytes: `My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(f)`

Comment: How does that differ from System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes???

Answer (score 32):

My 2 cents:

```
    using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.Open(zFile, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        foreach (var fPath in filePaths)
        {
            archive.CreateEntryFromFile(fPath,Path.GetFileName(fPath));
        }
    }
```

So Zip files could be created directly from files/dirs.

Comment: @RodrigoStrauss it's (dest, source)

Comment: what reference is ZipArchive from ? c# does not recognize it

Comment: ZipFile and ZipArchive come from the assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem and System.IO.Compression

Comment: This library is  only available from .NET framework 4.5

Comment: This is the most concise answer for me. +1

Answer (score 20):

Here are a few resources you might consider:
[Creating Zip archives in .NET (without an external library like SharpZipLib)](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/10/25/creating-zip-archives-in-net-without-an-external-library-like-sharpziplib.aspx)

[Zip Your Streams with System.IO.Packaging](http://madprops.org/blog/zip-your-streams-with-system-io-packaging/)

My recommendation and preference would be to use system.io.packacking.  This keeps your dependencies down (just the framework).
Jgalloway’s post (the first reference) provides a good example of adding two files to a zip file.  Yes, it is more verbose, but you can easily create a façade (to a degree his AddFileToZip does that).

HTH

Answer (score 6):

You can try [SharpZipLib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) for that. Is is open source, platform independent pure c# code.

Answer (score 5):

.NET has a built functionality for compressing files in the [System.IO.Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.aspx) namespace. Using this you do not have to take an extra library as a dependency. This functionality is available from .NET 2.0.

Here is the way to do the compressing from the MSDN page I linked:

```
    public static void Compress(FileInfo fi)
    {
        // Get the stream of the source file.
        using (FileStream inFile = fi.OpenRead())
        {
            // Prevent compressing hidden and already compressed files.
            if ((File.GetAttributes(fi.FullName) & FileAttributes.Hidden)
                    != FileAttributes.Hidden & fi.Extension != ".gz")
            {
                // Create the compressed file.
                using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(fi.FullName + ".gz"))
                {
                    using (GZipStream Compress = new GZipStream(outFile,
                            CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        // Copy the source file into the compression stream.
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                        int numRead;
                        while ((numRead = inFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
                        {
                            Compress.Write(buffer, 0, numRead);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Compressed {0} from {1} to {2} bytes.",
                            fi.Name, fi.Length.ToString(), outFile.Length.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is for Single file. how to do with multiple files

Answer (score 4):

You should look into [Zip Packages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.packaging.zippackage%28VS.85%29.aspx)

They are a more structured version of normal ZIP archives, requiring some meta stuff in the root. So other ZIP tools can open a package, but the Sysytem.IO.Packaging API can not open all ZIP files.

Answer (score 1):

**This can be done by adding a reference to System.IO.Compression and System.IO.Compression.Filesystem.**

A sample createZipFile() method may look as following:

```
public static void createZipFile(string inputfile, string outputfile, CompressionLevel compressionlevel)
        {
            try
            {
                using (ZipArchive za = ZipFile.Open(outputfile, ZipArchiveMode.Update))
                {
                    //using the same file name as entry name
                    za.CreateEntryFromFile(inputfile, inputfile);
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input/output file.");
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
}
```

**where**

- inputfile= string with the file name to be compressed (for this
  example, you have to add the extension)
- outputfile= string with the destination zip file name

[More details about ZipFile Class in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I wrote after using the above posts. Thanks for all your help.

This code accepts a list of file paths and creates a zip file out of them.

```
public class Zip
{
    private string _filePath;
    public string FilePath { get { return _filePath; } }

    /// <summary>
    /// Zips a set of files
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filesToZip">A list of filepaths</param>
    /// <param name="sZipFileName">The file name of the new zip (do not include the file extension, nor the full path - just the name)</param>
    /// <param name="deleteExistingZip">Whether you want to delete the existing zip file</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Limitation - all files must be in the same location. 
    /// Limitation - must have read/write/edit access to folder where first file is located.
    /// Will throw exception if the zip file already exists and you do not specify deleteExistingZip
    /// </remarks>
    public Zip(List<string> filesToZip, string sZipFileName, bool deleteExistingZip = true)
    {
        if (filesToZip.Count > 0)
        {
            if (File.Exists(filesToZip[0]))
            {

                // Get the first file in the list so we can get the root directory
                string strRootDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filesToZip[0]);

                // Set up a temporary directory to save the files to (that we will eventually zip up)
                DirectoryInfo dirTemp = Directory.CreateDirectory(strRootDirectory + "/" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss"));

                // Copy all files to the temporary directory
                foreach (string strFilePath in filesToZip)
                {
                    if (!File.Exists(strFilePath))
                    {
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("File {0} does not exist", strFilePath));
                    }
                    string strDestinationFilePath = Path.Combine(dirTemp.FullName, Path.GetFileName(strFilePath));
                    File.Copy(strFilePath, strDestinationFilePath);
                }

                // Create the zip file using the temporary directory
                if (!sZipFileName.EndsWith(".zip")) { sZipFileName += ".zip"; }
                string strZipPath = Path.Combine(strRootDirectory, sZipFileName);
                if (deleteExistingZip == true && File.Exists(strZipPath)) { File.Delete(strZipPath); }
                ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(dirTemp.FullName, strZipPath, CompressionLevel.Fastest, false);

                // Delete the temporary directory
                dirTemp.Delete(true);

                _filePath = strZipPath;                    
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("File {0} does not exist", filesToZip[0]));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("You must specify at least one file to zip.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with just one line of code using just Dot Net. Below is sample code copied from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx)

Step 1: Add a reference to System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

Step 2: Follow the code below

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string startPath = @"c:\example\start";
            string zipPath = @"c:\example\result.zip";
            string extractPath = @"c:\example\extract";

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath);

            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
        }
```

Comment: This only creates the empty zip itself you need to use ZipArchive