# Return list of images from web API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a web API with MVC and C#, I try to return a list of images which are stored in folder and paths of them in the database, I'm trying that:

```
 public class Image {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int Item_Id { get; set; }
    public bool isMain { get; set; }
}
```

and in image controller I call this method:

```
 [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("GetImageByItemId")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetImages(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                var entity = ctx.Images.Where(e => e.Item_Id == id).ToList();

                // ctx.Images.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Item_Id == id);
                if (entity != null)
                {
                    List<HttpResponseMessage> shapes = new List<HttpResponseMessage>();
                    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
                    for (int i = 0; i < entity.Count; i++)
                    { 

                    String filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/Images/" + entity[i].Path + ".jpg");
                    FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
                    response.Content = new StreamContent(fileStream); // this file stream will be closed by lower layers of web api for you once the response is completed.
                    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
                    shapes.Add(response);
                    }
                     // return response;
                    // return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, shapes);
                    return ControllerContext.Request
        .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new {shapes});
                }
                else
                {
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "The Images With ID" + id.ToString() + " Not Found");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }
```

if I use

```
return response;
```

or

```
return  shapes[1];
```

it's work to return one image but I need it return a list of image, how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to download multiple files with one HTTP request?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041542/how-to-download-multiple-files-with-one-http-request)

Comment: @SandRock I not need to download multiple files, I need to return list of images to show them in another application that use this wep API.

Answer (score 0):

**One HTTP response can contain zero or one (1) content. No more.**

### The logical solution

If you want to serve multiple files, you will need to make as many requests as necessary.

First, make a MVC action that will return a list of the files available for a given entity id.

Then, make a MVC action that will take the entity id *and* the file id as parameter.

On the client side, start by calling the first method. Then call the second one as many times as there are files to download.

### The package solution

You can also package multiple files into one file (zip, tar, 7zip...) using [System.IO.Packaging](http://madprops.org/blog/zip-your-streams-with-system-io-packaging/) or a [known library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2454956/282105).

### The alien solution

You may also try to implement the [MIME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) specification on both server and client side. Be warned: current web browsers do not implement it. This clearly is *non-standard* therefore *not recommended*. [This article](http://www.motobit.com/tips/detpg_multiple-files-one-request/) seems to address the technique.

Comment: No, I need to show them in another application.
So are  there any other method to do that and return a list of images?