# How I can attach a folder in SendGrid email

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I am using SendGrid to send email using C# from visual Studio.  I have been successful sending email so far.

Now I want to attach a zip folder to the email that is I am creating using SendGrid.  How I can attach a zip folder?

I have seen example for pdf, jpeg but I am specific about zip file or folder, in other words what would be the varible of the attachement properties following below:

```
attachment = new Attachment()
        {
            Content = ?,
            Type = ?
            Filename = "MyFilesFolder2.zip",
            Disposition = "inline",
            ContentId = ?
        };
```

Thanks

Comment: Actually, I am not talking about just any document I am talking about zip file.   What would be the value of the attachment  variable when attaching the zip to an email.

Comment: You don't need to change these values from their default values. `myMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("C:\Path\To\MyFilesFolder2.zip"));` will work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be confused by MS Windows displaying ZIP files as folders. ZIP files are not folders, they are just files, like any other file.

Thus, you'd add them to an e-mail just like you would add any other file. See the following SO question for details:

- [Adding an attachment to email using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5034503/87698)

If you don't have a ZIP file yet and want to create one (based on an existing folder), that's an entirely different question. Fortunately, it has been answered here as well:

- [Create normal zip file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2454956/87698)